# Django ORM save object with all related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In my development I've got in situation when I need to save the model object with the all selected, related objects. Sounds weird but it is useful when you don't know which operations was done with the model object.
Example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Room(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    size_x = models.SmallIntegerField()
    size_y = models.SmallIntegerField()

def do_some_stuff(room):
    room.user.name = "some new name"         

room = Room.objects.get(id="some_id")
do_some_stuff(room) # we didn't know which related_fields would be loaded and modified here
room.save() # <- here I want to save the room object and the user (if the user object was fetched or modified from db)
```

Maybe there are some way how I can recursively get the all related objects which was loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: Although it can be done, this looks like bad design, usually the idea is that every object is responsible for itself.

Comment: I need to pass the room object through the many processors which could do any logic, and in the end of all I wan't to save the data which was modified.

Comment: Yeah, but chains of calls is anti-pattern as well: https://refactoring.guru/smells/message-chains (overview: https://refactoring.guru/refactoring/smells)